# If the data is isotropic then why the covariance is proportional to the unit matrix?

Tags: machine-learning

I know that if it is isotropic so the number on the diagnal should be the same. But why the covariance is diagonal? If the data is isotropic means every dimension is independent?

Answer (score 0):

Right.  The covariance matrix is diagonal **iff** the variables are independent.  In terms of linear algebra, this means that the dependencies can all be eliminated.  The matrix form of this is a diagonal matrix.

Does that clear up your confusion?